# N v2.0 insta-kill on level 8.5

Tags: macos, n-way-of-the-ninja

I'm playing N (Way of the Ninja) version 2.0, level 8.5 insta-kills me, sending me back to the title screen, It appears that I run out of time before the level even starts:

[image]

Comment: I removed the "drawing" because it wasn't clear, you'd better edit the image to highlight the level if really needed.

Answer (score 1):

So, It appears to be a bug, Because I now have 35 seconds left in the timer, instead of 0.3 seconds in the level. It must have been a one-off bug.